# Norm of functional associated to vector $p$-norm

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I read that the norm of a linear functional $f:V\to K$, with $K=\mathbb{R}\lor K=\mathbb{C}$, associated to the $p$-norm $\|x\|=(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$, for $p>1$, is $$\|f\|=\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n|f(e_i)|^q\Big)^{\frac{1}{q}}$$

where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$ and $e_i,i=1,...,n$ are the elements of the basis of $V$.

Does anybody know a link to a proof or a proof of the fact that $\|f\|:=\sup_{\|x\|=1}|f(x)|=\sup_{\|x\|\leq 1}|f(x)|=\sup_{x\ne 0}\frac{|f(x)|}{\|x\|}$ is equal to $(\sum_{i=1}^n|f(e_i)|^q)^{\frac{1}{q}}$?

I know that for any $x=a_1 e_1+...+a_n e_n$ we have $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_if(e_i)$, but I cannot go further...

EDIT: I thank all the users that have linked the other question bearing a strong similarity with mine. I'm not deleting it, though, because I suppose the slight difference can make it useful for future readers of this site.

Comment: The heart of the matter is Hölder's inequality (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder's_inequality), which gives you the inequality $\|f\| \leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n |f(e_i)|^q\right)^{1/q}$. Getting an equality, however, requires cooking up the right $p$-norm unit vector $x$, but this won't be hard to reverse engineer in your finite-dimensional setting.

Comment: $\infty$ thanks for the hint!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build on the identity that you found:
$$
        f\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{j}e_{j}\right) = \sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{j}f(e_{j})
$$
The way you build on this is to choose $a_{j}$ so that $a_{j}f(e_{j})=|f(e_{j})|^{q}$. Then you get
$$
\begin{align}
    \sum_{j=1}^{n}|f(e_{j})|^{q}
        & \le \|f\|\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}|a_{j}|^p\right)^{1/p} \\
        & = \|f\|\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}|f(e_{j})|^{p(q-1)}\right)^{1/p} \\
        & = \|f\|\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}|f(e_{j})|^{q}\right)^{1/p}.
\end{align}
$$
So that implies
$$
      \left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}|f(e_{j})|^{q}\right)^{1/q} \le \|f\|.
$$
I'll bet you can take it from there.

Comment: $\infty$ thanks!!! So $\forall j=1,...,n\quad a_j=|f(e_j)|^{q-1}\Rightarrow |f(x)|/\|x\|=\|f\|$.